Want to get X divs under each other with some height that dont get changed
I want x divs under each other with some height(e.g 1/2 of screenheight) but when I do that, the divs get 1/x height because it tries to fill the screen with x divs so it makes it smaller but I dont want that.
Code I have in React using Tailwind:
import React from 'react';

function YourComponent() {
    return (
        <div className='flex flex-col justify-center items-center bg-white border border-black h-screen'>

            <div className="w-full h-1/2 border">
                Div 1
            </div>
            <div className="w-full h-1/2 border">
                Div 2
            </div>
            <div className="w-full h-1/2 border">
                Div 3
            </div>
            <div className="w-full h-1/2 border">
                Div 4
            </div>
            <div className="w-full h-1/2 border">
                Div 5
            </div>

        </div>
    );
}

export default YourComponent;


Items in a flex layout have flex-shrink: 1 by default, which lets them shrink to fit inside the flex layout's major axis.
Thus, to avoid them shrinking, consider applying flex-shrink: 0 via the shrink-0 Tailwind class:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div class='flex flex-col justify-center items-center bg-white border border-black h-screen'>
  <div class="w-full h-1/2 border shrink-0">
    Div 1
  </div>
  <div class="w-full h-1/2 border shrink-0">
    Div 2
  </div>
  <div class="w-full h-1/2 border shrink-0">
    Div 3
  </div>
  <div class="w-full h-1/2 border shrink-0">
    Div 4
  </div>
  <div class="w-full h-1/2 border shrink-0">
    Div 5
  </div>
</div>



